# ZPL printing Null filed BarCode image

Tags: zpl

How to prevent disply of barcode image for Null field passed to ZPL template, so if the field is Null the image should not print,

Comment: You need to parse the ZPL code to delete the **whole** barcode command in that case before it is send to the printer.

Comment: Thnaks Mate, Can you give me an example for ZPL command code, I'm using ZPL template which reading from SQL StoreProcedure and passing fields to the template, however, this BarCode image can sometimes have value which is needed and sometimes it's Null, and once it's having empty value or Null, I dont want the image of BarCode to be printed, I tried to code Isnull(field, space) which return space value or empty instead of null, but that also did not workout with ZPL, the filed still printing the barcode image all the times.

Comment: There is no example ZPL command for this task. You need to delete the Barcode command from the template string. And you did not even say, which programming language you are using.

Comment: Hi, I'm referring to ZPL language, I thought its obvious to have ZPL template written in ZPL language.

Comment: ZPL code passing no value is here with for both Null and Empty value, both return with the print of barcode image that I'm trying to get rid off.

Comment: ^XA
^FO400,800
^BY4,3.5
^BCN,80,Y,N
^FD>;>8Nulll^FS

^FO400,800
^BY4,3.5
^BCN,80,Y,N
^FD>;>8^FS

^XZ

Comment: ZPL is a markup language. You need to process it somehow.

Comment: Still no answer which programming language you are using. There are ZPL frameworks in several languages available.

Comment: Are you using XLM Templates?